# Pylance: remove the first module in auto import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

How can I force `pylance` to remove the first module in auto imports?

i.e. change

```
from backend.api.bills.serializers import ...
```

to

```
from api.bills.serializers import ...
```

I tries these `settings.json`:

```
{
    "python.linting.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}\\backend",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}\\backend\\.."],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}\\backend\\.."],
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on why one might need this, but I think you can open your editor from inside the `backend/` folder and trick pylance

```bash
code /path/to/backend/
```

Comment: That's true, but i work on `backend` and `frontend` simultaneously, for your idea to work, i need to open 2  instances of Vscode.

Comment: Again, not entirely sure if this is ideal, but you can open the backend as so then go to the explorer tab, right click and `Add folder to Workspace` to add the frontend to the same workspace

Answer (score 0):

Vscode is retrieved from the workspace as the root directory. Even if you change "cmd" in setting.json, there is no way to change the search method of vscode.

The only solution is to specify the `backend` as the new workspace and edit your file from this new workspace.